# PHP Subtraction

Tags: php, redirect, logic, subtraction

I have to subtract a number from another number, but the script must verify that this is possible without giving a negative number.

For example, the client's credit is $5.00. They want to make a purchase of $20, now they are short by $15 so they cannot make the purchase. Now it must redirect them to a page (Insuffient funds).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$toBill = 20.0;
$myMoney = 5.0;

if( $myMoney >= $toBill )
{
  // process
  $myMoney -= $toBill;
}
else
{
  // error
  header('Location: /error_nsf/');
  exit;
}
```

**EDIT:** This question screams that you've not sufficiently learned the basics. You should go read about flow constructs and conditionals and such, things like this will become much much easier if you do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic conditional,

```
$balance = 5.00;
$debit   = 20.00;
if ($debit > $balance) {
    // handle the error
} else {
    $balance -= $debit;
}
```

Comment: Over complicating the conditional IMO.

Comment: @webnoob: how else would you do it?

Comment: @nico: I believe prior to his edit he was subtracting and possibly assigning inside of the `if` statement. This version is much simpler, albeit a copy of what I wrote.

Comment: @Nico - He edited his post; it did say (0 > $balance - $debit).

Comment: @Umbrella - It's very silly to not put a comment for your edit when you change something like that.

Comment: @webnoob: ah OK, now it makes sense :)

Comment: You are correct.  Immediately noticing how silly the first condition was, I hoped to edit it before anyone noticed.  You are all to fast for me.  Josh's answer (+1) is better anyway, as he thought to include the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$toBill = 20.0;
$myMoney = 5.0;

$myMoney = $toBill <= $myMoney ? $myMoney - $toBill : header('Location: insuficcientFunds.php');
```

Comment: Correct? Yes. Way overcomplicated to expect the OP to understand ternary operations when they don't know a basic `if`? Yes.

Comment: @Josh - It's the correct solution IMO but I agree looking at the OP it is over complicated.

Comment: It is more complicated, but for a simple redirect I think it's more readable then if-else cosntructs.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use a function that checks if a purchase is valid, in regards to the credit value, like so:

```
function purchaseIsValid( $purchaseValue, $creditValue )
{
    return ($purchaseValue <= $creditValue ); // returns true or false
}
```

And then in you main application do something like everyone suggested:

```
$purchase = 20.0;
$credit = 5.0;
if( purchaseIsValid( $purchase, $credit ))
{
    // process
}
else
{
    // error
}
```

Have a great day!